# Find the solution for the PDE system with initial condition.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Find the solution for the problem:

$
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2} -c^2\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}=0\qquad \qquad x\in\mathbb{R}\;,t>0 \\
u(x,0)=e^{-x^2} \qquad \qquad \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}(x,0)=\cos x
\end{equation}
$

**My attempt:**

We know the general solution of wave equation is: $$u(x,t)=F(x-ct)+G(x+ct)\tag 1$$

We need find $F$ and $G$ such that $(1)$ satifies the initial condition of the problem.

Then,

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=-cF'(x-ct)+cG'(x+ct)$$

Moreover

$u(x,0)=e^{-x^2}\implies F(x)+G(x)=e^{-x^2} \tag 2$

$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}(x,0)=\cos x \implies -cF'(x)+cG'(x)=\cos x\tag 3$

of $(2)$ and $(3)$ we can get the value of $G'(x)$

In other words,

$$G'(x)=-xe^{-x^2}+\frac{\cos x}{2c} \tag 4$$

Integrating $(4)$of $0$ to $x$ we have:

$$G(x)=\frac{1}{2}[e^{-x^2}-1+\frac{\sin x}{c}] + G(0)\tag 5$$

As $F(x)=e^{-x^2}-G(x)$ then:

$$F(x)=e^{-x^2}-\frac{1}{2}[e^{-x^2}-1+\frac{\sin x}{c}] - G(0) \tag 6$$

Replacing $(5)$, $(6)$ in $(1)$ we have:

$$u(x,t)=e^{-x^2}-\frac{1}{2}[e^{-x^2}-1+\frac{\sin x}{c}]+\frac{1}{2}[e^{-x^2}-1+\frac{\sin x}{c}] \tag 7$$

I think this last result is wrong because $(7)$ expression does not satisfy the principal PDE.

Can someone help me?

Comment: In (7) you have $u(x,t) = F(x)+G(x)$, but shouldn't it be $u(x,t) = F(x-ct)+G(x+ct)$, according to (1)?

Comment: true, i go to correct that @rafa11111

Comment: your u only depends on x not on t  normally it should depends also on t

Comment: yes, i have a mistake in the solution when i substitute the solution $(7)$. $u(x,t)=F(x-ct)+G(x+ct)$ i substitute $u(x,t)=F(x)+G(x)$ @Isham

Comment: yes you should substitute $F(x-ct)$ to keep the dependencies on t ...